# Ubuntu won't compile a C file, error "<drfftw_mpi.h>: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, fftw

For context, I am trying to run the makefile for the [NGenIC](https://www.h-its.org/2014/11/05/ngenic-code/) code (written for a fortran simulation). Despite successfully configuring the code, Ubuntu seems to not like the filepath to the installed libraries, despite it working for the main code. Is there any remedy to this?

```
 cc    -DNO64BITID      -O3 -Wall  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/common/pdsoft/include   -c -o main.o main.c
    main.c:3:10: fatal error: drfftw_mpi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <drfftw_mpi.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    <builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Does the main code use the d- (double precision) FFTW headers and libraries, or some other flavour? Do you have those installed? At first glance I can't see which Ubuntu packages provide the d- files, though, and it looks like the default versions (without the 'd') might be double.

Comment: As far as I know it's configured for single precision. I'm not sure why it can't find the libraries

Comment: My apologies--I solved it by installing the double precision mode

Comment: Save others some time and answer your own question.

Comment: @H98 did you just install "libfftw3-double3" or something else too? I already have that and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

So I know this is an old thread but my solution was simple. I was installing the files in a directory I created rather than the main one Ubuntu uses.

Comment: Was this directory the reason for the problem or was it the solution?

Comment: It was both. I fixed it by navigating to my main directory